# Ubuntu 16.04; unable to set Static IP Address

Tags: networking, server

New installation of Ubuntu 16.04/64 on new computer. I wish to set a Static IP Address. DHCP works without a problem, but is not practical for a server.

Using a local computer, and using the address (192.168.1.200) to open the Apache2 Page, my connection times out.

Content of `/etc/network/interfaces` :

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface  
# auto enp4s0
# iface enp4s0 inet dhcp

# Static IP Address Assignment
auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet static
address 198.162.1.200
netmask 255.255.255.255
network 192.168.1.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

I have used ifdown, ip addr flush xxxx, and ifup, to stop and start the Ethernet.  As well as reboot the machine several times.

Comment: When you use DHCP, what address do you get? `ifconfig` And what route? `route -n` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Look again in `/etc/network/interfaces` in your question address is `address 198.162.1.200`. Probably is typo, but check again.

Answer (score 2):

Your network mask should not be 255.255.255.255 it should be 255.255.255.0 (I think). The format of the network mask is 255 for any network numbers (if that makes sense) and 0 for the host.

I think your file should be:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface  
# auto enp4s0
# iface enp4s0 inet dhcp

# Static IP Address Assignment
auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet static
address 192.168.1.200
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Changed netmask to 255.255.255.0, without result.  Continue to have connection issues.

Comment: Did you change your address from 198.162.1.200? It should be 192.168.1.200

Comment: I have not learned how to capture a screen running the server. The 198.x.x.x to 192.x.x.x, was the issue.   Guess my eyes are getting too old.  I spent about six hours on Saturday with this.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above wrong netmask. Remove the `network`-line it is not necessary.

You also might want to disable the `network-manager.service`. Since this one might cause troubles if it doesn't recognize your static config.

I have also just noticed you have a mistake in your IP address.
`address 198.162.1.200` should be `address 192.168.1.200` or it will never work.

Comment: This is a server, without a GUI.  Network-manager.service does not exist.

Comment: Did you remove the network line?

Comment: Thank you, this has been resolved. I am unable to locate a method to mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following configuration and run `sudo service network-manager restart`
and `sudo service networking restart`

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface  
# auto enp4s0
# iface enp4s0 inet dhcp

# Static IP Address Assignment
auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet static
   address 198.162.1.200
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 192.168.1.1
   dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```